# Lifetime issue while implementing a trait for a generic type which implements a trait with an associated lifetime

Tags: rust, json-deserialization, lifetime, serde

I am writing a deserializer (`Vec<u8>` (Raw JSON) to any type T) for a project and trying to use serde for it. Here's my trait which I to decode the data:

```rust
pub trait Decode: Sized {
    fn try_decode(input: Vec<u8>) -> Result<Self, InternalError>;
}
```

Since I intend to use `#[derive(Deserialize)]` on my structs, I am writing an impl for any type that implements the Deserialize trait with an arbitrary lifetime:

```rust
impl<'a, T: Deserialize<'a>> Decode for T {
    fn try_decode(input: Vec<u8>) -> Result<Self, InternalError> {
        if let Ok(t) = serde_json::from_slice(&input) {
            Ok(t)
        } else {
            Err(Internal::decode("Could not decode"))
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting a lifetime error:

```
error[E0597]: `input` does not live long enough
  --> src/decode.rs:16:47
   |
14 | impl<'a, T: Deserialize<'a>> Decode for T {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
15 |     fn try_decode(input: Vec<u8>) -> Result<Self, InternalError> {
16 |         if let Ok(t) = serde_json::from_slice(&input) {
   |                        -----------------------^^^^^^-
   |                        |                      |
   |                        |                      borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                        argument requires that `input` is borrowed for `'a`
...
21 |     }
   |     - `input` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I understand why the compiler is mad at me. Upon checking the implementation of from_slice, I figured it has an associated lifetime. I am sure input is an owned value, but from_slice requires a reference, so here I am returning reference of a value which gets dropped when the function ends, which is clearly incorrect. My question is, is there a way to ensure that the value is borrowed for <'a> lifetime (i.e. the lifetime supplied by the caller of this function). I can't update the trait because it will cause a disaster.

Comment: If you want a value that doesn't borrow from the slice, you can use `DeserializeOwned` as the trait bound, which has no associated lifetime (and therefore only stores owned values). For example, [this compiles](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f54236f04db830586ffb62c048d06d66).

Comment: Yep, found this solution in other channel, thanks! Answering my own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a value that doesn't borrow from the slice, you can use [`DeserializeOwned`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde/de/trait.DeserializeOwned.html) as the trait bound, which has no associated lifetime (and therefore only stores owned values). For example, this compiles:

```
impl<T: DeserializeOwned> Decode for T {
    fn try_decode(input: Vec<u8>) -> Result<Self, InternalError> {
        if let Ok(t) = serde_json::from_slice(&input) {
            Ok(t)
        } else {
            todo!()
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f54236f04db830586ffb62c048d06d66)

This is equivalent to using a higher-ranked trait bound with the lower-level `Deserialize` trait bound:

```
impl<T: for<'de> Deserialize<'de>> Decode for T {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining and other solution as well! :)

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to use Deserialize with a lifetime is using [Higher Rank Trait Bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html#higher-rank-trait-bounds-hrtbs): Specifically telling compiler that this lifetime is valid for all (concerned) lifetimes using the `for<'a>` notation. The code will look like this:

```rust
impl<T: for<'de> Deserialize<'de>> InputCoercible for T {
    // ...trait methods...
}
```

Comment: If his answer helped you, please [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) instead of posting a separate "thank you" answer so people know that the question has been answered.

Comment: Note that the HRTB shown here and `DeserializeOwned` are equally "correct" and are in fact equivalent ([docs](https://serde.rs/lifetimes.html#trait-bounds)). `DeserializeOwned` was introduced precisely so you wouldn't have to spell out the higher-ranked trait bound every time you need to specify `Deserialize` for any lifetime.

Comment: Ah okay! Thank you so much! While you explained exactly how they are functionally similar, I had asked about using Deserialize and how can I validate the life of borrow. Your answer did help me, but I believe knowledge of HRTB was the key. I would really appreciate if you add both HRTB and `DeserializeOwned` to your answer so that I can mark it accepted again. :)

Comment: Hi, I haven't seen your comment (until now) because it didn't contain an `@...` marker to trigger a notification. I've now edited the answer as requested.